# php - if post is query string, do this

Tags: php

I am receiving webhooks from 2 servers: one in json, and one is a query string. I need something like, "If the post is a query string, do this. else, do this"

All I have working so far is just writing both of them.

```
$rawString  = $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$rawData    = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data       = json_decode($rawData, true);

date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');

//write the raw webhook (including headers) to a logfile named webhook.log
$date          = new DateTime();
$headers       = apache_request_headers();
$stringMessage = (print_r($headers, true)) . $rawString;
$message       = (print_r($headers, true)) . $rawData;

error_log($date->format("F j Y, g:i:s a T") . "\n" . "NOT QUERY STRING" . "\n" . $message . "\n\n\n", 3, 'webhook.log');
error_log($date->format("F j Y, g:i:s a T") . "\n" . "QUERY STRING" . "\n" . $stringMessage . "\n\n\n", 3, 'webhook.log');

echo 'Post successfully captured';
```

Comment: You need to know how to write an `if` statement?

Comment: What do you mean? "If query string do this, else is json so do this" or just want to get the type? If first try parsing json handling the Exception. If seccond, use gettype() http://php.net/manual/es/function.gettype.php

Comment: Also, a query string usually denotes a GET request so just check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

Comment: The query string should be read from both `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and, if it's not there, from `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. Also, if your app moves to a server that is not Apache, then you have to read the headers from the `$_SERVER` variable (e.g. the items having their keys starting with the "HTTP_" and "CONTENT_" substrings).

Comment: you way too many unclosed questions, IMHO. This doesn't look well on your track record.